# Android SurfaceView, thread for drawing, lockCanvas in infinite loop

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to use widely-used(according to google) approach for creating canvas drawing in separate thread, it uses thread like below

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (running) {
        c=null;
        try { 
            c = mySurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null); 
        } ....
```

Here I have infinite loop with calling lockCanvas() method, but I'm confused - sometimes lockCanvas() method is extremely slow and coupled with the fact that I have infinite loop - I have really bad performance sometimes.

Could you please advise, how can I avoid this performance issue and is there any other approach for drawing on canvas?

Comment: Maybe the problem is situated elsewhere. In my own rendering code, I use a very similar approach and even create a new Canvas reference and object in each pass of the loop, yet I get excellent framerate.

Comment: @npace Profiling shows that _lockCanvas()_ takes the largest time..

Comment: Hmm, I can't really check if its the same for me, but it's possible that lockCanvas takes a long time to complete, but does not impact performance on its own...

Comment: Actually I'm a little bit confused by this 'infinite loop' with _lockCanvas()_ method... I'm not sure - is it a really good way?

Comment: Well, it's the accepted way for simple graphics. If you need better performance, you should use OpenGL instead of the Canvas API. If you want, you can take a look at a simple snake game I've implemented with Canvas to compare your own code - https://github.com/npace/DroidSnake . Haven't uploaded anything with OpenGL yet, though...